# Expanding a dynamic macro inside printf function

Tags: c, gcc, macros, printf

I want to compile a c program under different names. In the main file, I have the following macro:

```
#ifndef EXECUTABLE_NAME
#define EXECUTABLE_NAME         "defaultname"
#endif
```

When compiling using gcc, I use `-D` switch to define this macro (is that the right term?):

```
$ gcc main.c -DEXECUTABLE_NAME="newname"
```

I do not know if the -D works fine or not because when I try to do something like the code below...it fails...I can not tell if the -D switch is screwing up or the syntax of using the macro inside the `printf()` function is not correct:

```
printf("no or invalid arguments. usage: %s [0,255]\n", EXECUTABLE_NAME);
```

I get this error:

```
main.c:48:57: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXECUTABLE_NAME’
  printf("no or invalid arguments. usage: %s [0,255]\n", EXECUTABLE_NAME);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, and you can see that *because* of the error. Which by the way is because you're defining your macro wrong on the command line, this is how you quote a string in a macro:

```
$ gcc main.c -DEXECUTABLE_NAME='"newname"'
```

And this said, it's not even needed. The executable path is always your first argument: `*argv`.

Comment: Does the `argv[0]` give the executable name e.g. `myapp` or something like `./myapp` or even `/path/to/myapp` ? I only need the pure application executable name

Comment: Try it and see, it's platform specific.

Comment: It's not hard to look for the last slash if it exists and display the string after it. Plus it will be copy-proof, if the user copies your executable under a different name.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this program with an integer, which is as follows

```
#ifndef EXECUTABLE_NAME
#define EXECUTABLE_NAME 2
#endif

int main()
{
  printf("%d",EXECUTABLE_NAME);
}
```

and then typed gcc main.c -DEXECUTABLE_NAME=1 and it works as the value changes to 1. Is it a problem with the data type 'string' that you are using?